# Need a complete sample to handle unhandled exceptions using "ExceptionHandler" in ASP.NET Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

I had checked this link
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling.
In this link they mentioned like this

```
class OopsExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
        {
            Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
            Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." +
                      "Please contact support@contoso.com so we can try to fix it."
        };
    }

    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = 
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to call this class in my Web API actions. So can any one give me the complete sample using this `ExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Good question! One would expect that the information which OP is seeking would be part of the MSDN article - it is only mentioned vaguely: `We provide two new user-replaceable services, IExceptionLogger and IExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your WebApi config your need to add the line:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionHandler), new OopsExceptionHandler());
```

Also make sure you have created the base ExceptionHandler class that implements IExceptionHandler:

```
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public virtual Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, 
                                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!ShouldHandle(context))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        return HandleAsyncCore(context, cancellationToken);
    }

    public virtual Task HandleAsyncCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context, 
                                       CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HandleCore(context);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public virtual void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
    }

    public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        return context.CatchBlock.IsTopLevel;
    }
}
```

Note that this will only deal with exceptions that are not handled elsewhere (e.g. by Exception filters).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.What is the difference between IHttpActionInvoker,IExceptionhandler in Web Api.

Comment: **IsOutermostCatchBlock** does not exists, use **CatchBlock.IsTopLevel** instead. See stackoverflow.com/a/22357634/1480391. BTW, this is the source of your example, with much more details: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling

Answer (score 92):

### You don't need to implement IExceptionHandler low-level mechanism yourself.

Instead, you can simply inherit from [ExceptionHandler](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandler) and override the [Handle](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandler/M/Handle) method.

```
public class MyExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler
{
  public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
  {
    //TODO: Do what you need to do
    base.Handle(context);
  }
}
```

[ExceptionHandler](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandler) implements [IExceptionHandler](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http/IExceptionHandler) and manage basic core mechanisms (like async and that exception should be handled or not).

Use your exception handler like that:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());
```

---

### Source

[This page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling) explains how to implements IExceptionHandler, but there are some typos and the code does not reflect the latest version of WebApi.

There is no documentation about the `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling` namespace (a little bit on [NuDoq](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http/System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling)).

So.. <s>using a [.NET assembly decompiler](http://ilspy.net/)</s> having a look at [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandling/ExceptionHandler.cs), I saw the `ExceptionHandler` class which implements `IExceptionHandler` and have some virtual methods.

ExceptionHandler looks like that:

```
namespace System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling
{
    /// <summary>Represents an unhandled exception handler.</summary>
    public abstract class ExceptionHandler: IExceptionHandler
    {
        /// <returns>Returns <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task" />.</returns>
        Task IExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            ExceptionContext arg_14_0 = context.ExceptionContext;
            if (!this.ShouldHandle(context))
            {
                return TaskHelpers.Completed();
            }
            return this.HandleAsync(context, cancellationToken);
        }

        /// <summary>When overridden in a derived class, handles the exception asynchronously.</summary>
        /// <returns>A task representing the asynchronous exception handling operation.</returns>
        /// <param name="context">The exception handler context.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The token to monitor for cancellation requests.</param>
        public virtual Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            this.Handle(context);
            return TaskHelpers.Completed();
        }

        /// <summary>When overridden in a derived class, handles the exception synchronously.</summary>
        /// <param name="context">The exception handler context.</param>
        public virtual void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>Determines whether the exception should be handled.</summary>
        /// <returns>true if the exception should be handled; otherwise, false.</returns>
        /// <param name="context">The exception handler context.</param>
        public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            ExceptionContext exceptionContext = context.ExceptionContext;
            ExceptionContextCatchBlock catchBlock = exceptionContext.CatchBlock;
            return catchBlock.IsTopLevel;
        }
    }
}
```

You can clearly see that `ShouldHandle` is implemented using `ExceptionContextCatchBlock.IsTopLevel` and that `HandleAsync` calls `Handle` :)

I hope this will helps until complete documentation shows up.

Comment: Precisely, no need to reimplement the base class. Also, nowadays the source is available on GitHub: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandling/ExceptionHandler.cs

Comment: @SørenBoisen Thanks I put it on the answser ;)

Answer (score 4):

As per Jon Susiak's answer you need to use:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof (IExceptionHandler), new OopsExceptionHandler());
```

Note the `Replace` call, not an `Add`. 
The reason for this is as per the article at this link:

[Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling)

> **Solution Overview**
>
> We provide two new user-replaceable services, IExceptionLogger and
>   IExceptionHandler, to log and handle unhandled exceptions.
>
> The
>   services are very similar, with two main differences:
>
> **We support registering multiple exception loggers but only a single
>    exception handler**.

And since there is already a handler registered by default you can't add another.

```
public DefaultServices(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
      if (configuration == null)
        throw System.Web.Http.Error.ArgumentNull("configuration");
      this._configuration = configuration;
      this.SetSingle<IActionValueBinder>((IActionValueBinder) new DefaultActionValueBinder());
      this.SetSingle<IApiExplorer>((IApiExplorer) new ApiExplorer(configuration));
      this.SetSingle<IAssembliesResolver>((IAssembliesResolver) new DefaultAssembliesResolver());
      this.SetSingle<IBodyModelValidator>((IBodyModelValidator) new DefaultBodyModelValidator());
      this.SetSingle<IContentNegotiator>((IContentNegotiator) new DefaultContentNegotiator());
      this.SetSingle<IDocumentationProvider>((IDocumentationProvider) null);
      this.SetMultiple<IFilterProvider>((IFilterProvider) new ConfigurationFilterProvider(), (IFilterProvider) new ActionDescriptorFilterProvider());
      this.SetSingle<IHostBufferPolicySelector>((IHostBufferPolicySelector) null);
      this.SetSingle<IHttpActionInvoker>((IHttpActionInvoker) new ApiControllerActionInvoker());
      this.SetSingle<IHttpActionSelector>((IHttpActionSelector) new ApiControllerActionSelector());
      this.SetSingle<IHttpControllerActivator>((IHttpControllerActivator) new DefaultHttpControllerActivator());
      this.SetSingle<IHttpControllerSelector>((IHttpControllerSelector) new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(configuration));
      this.SetSingle<IHttpControllerTypeResolver>((IHttpControllerTypeResolver) new DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver());
      this.SetSingle<ITraceManager>((ITraceManager) new TraceManager());
      this.SetSingle<ITraceWriter>((ITraceWriter) null);
      this.SetMultiple<ModelBinderProvider>((ModelBinderProvider) new TypeConverterModelBinderProvider(), (ModelBinderProvider) new TypeMatchModelBinderProvider(), (ModelBinderProvider) new KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider(), (ModelBinderProvider) new ComplexModelDtoModelBinderProvider(), (ModelBinderProvider) new ArrayModelBinderProvider(), (ModelBinderProvider) new DictionaryModelBinderProvider(), (ModelBinderProvider) new CollectionModelBinderProvider(), (ModelBinderProvider) new MutableObjectModelBinderProvider());
      this.SetSingle<ModelMetadataProvider>((ModelMetadataProvider) new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider());
      this.SetMultiple<ModelValidatorProvider>((ModelValidatorProvider) new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider(), (ModelValidatorProvider) new DataMemberModelValidatorProvider());
      this.SetMultiple<ValueProviderFactory>((ValueProviderFactory) new QueryStringValueProviderFactory(), (ValueProviderFactory) new RouteDataValueProviderFactory());
      this.SetSingle<IModelValidatorCache>((IModelValidatorCache) new ModelValidatorCache(new Lazy<IEnumerable<ModelValidatorProvider>>((Func<IEnumerable<ModelValidatorProvider>>) (() => ServicesExtensions.GetModelValidatorProviders((ServicesContainer) this)))));

      this.SetSingle<IExceptionHandler>((IExceptionHandler) new DefaultExceptionHandler());

      this.SetMultiple<IExceptionLogger>();
      this._serviceTypesSingle = new HashSet<Type>((IEnumerable<Type>) this._defaultServicesSingle.Keys);
      this._serviceTypesMulti = new HashSet<Type>((IEnumerable<Type>) this._defaultServicesMulti.Keys);
      this.ResetCache();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following sample from Web API team:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/Elmah/ReadMe.txt